# Setting up SBPL (arm_planning) for MoveIt! with Setup Assistant

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

How can I embed sbpl instead of ompl in the MoveIt!-configuration files for Arm-Navigation?
I used the MoveIt! Setup Assistant, and it generates no sbpl_planning.yaml file.
When I load the RVIZ-Motion-Planning-Plugin automatically OMPL is loaded.

**Edit:** Is it possible at all?, because looking closer at the Setup Assistant I didn't find any option that indicates that.

Edit: I followed the advice of Jeremy.
But the Terminal shows following:

```
[ERROR] [1366832323.048313258]: Exception while loading planner 'sbpl_interface_ros/SBPLPlanner': According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class sbpl_interface_ros/SBPLPlanner with base class type planning_interface::Planner does not exist. Declared types are  ompl_interface_ros/OMPLPlanner
Available plugins: ompl_interface_ros/OMPLPlanner
```

**Edit:** I noticed (thanks to Jeremey) that no sbpl-plugin is installed.
Is there a binary plugin yet, bacause I could not find it.
If not how can I install SBPL from Source?

**Edit:** I put the smpl source folder in the catkin_workspace.
Unfortunately catkin_make failed.
executing rospack depends shows following:

```
 faps@faps-Aspire-5740D:~/catkin_ws$ rospack depends sbpl_interface_ros
[rospack] Error: package/stack 'sbpl_interface' depends on non-existent package 'planning_models' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'
```

1. Trying `'rosdep update'` results in
   `HTTP Error 404: Not Found`-Errors.
   Also there is no package
   `planning_models` listed when using
   `rospack list-names`. So, where can
   I get this package? (googling also
   failed)
2. How can I solve the message `rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency` ?

---

**Edit:** There is an additional missing package called `collision_distance_field`.
It is no single ros-package but is located in the package `moveit_core`.

So I did rosmake on the package `moveit_core`, but `collision_distance_field` is still missing.

I looked in CMakeLists.txt of `moveit_core` and there was no line with `collision_distance_field`.

What should I do?

Many Thanks in advance and
Greetz
rosrookie

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61364/setting-up-sbpl-(arm_planning)-for-moveit!-with-setup-assistant/) by [rosrookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/3050/rosrookie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2013-04-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know that you're able to configure this from within the Setup Assistant, but you should be able to modify the launch files to change the planning pipeline.  I haven't tried this myself, but it looks like you should be able to edit the `move_group.launch` in your moveit package:

```
<include ns="move_group" file="$(find my_robot_moveit_pkg)/launch/planning_pipeline.launch">
  <arg name="pipeline" value="ompl" />
</include>
```

If you change `"ompl"` to `"sbpl"` in `move_group.launch`, it will try to load `sbpl_planning_pipline.launch` instead of `ompl_planning_pipline.launch`.  My guess is that this should switch to using SBPL instead of OMPL and things should "just work".  But I haven't tried it yet, so good luck!

---

**Edit:**
It sounds like you may not have sbpl installed.  I don't know that there is a binary ubuntu package for SBPL/MoveIt yet, so you may need to download and install from source.

You can read [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pluginlib) for how plugins are integrated with ROS.  In summary, the package needs a few things to make the plugin work: an `export` tag in the `manifest.xml` (or `package.xml`) file tells the ROS build system to look for a `_plugins.xml` file which provides details on what classes and library files to look in for the actual plugin code.

It may help to use `rospack` to get a list of what plugins are currently found in your ROS installation:

```
rospack plugins --attrib=plugin moveit_core
```

If this list doesn't include a plugin for SBPL, then you won't be able to get it to work with the rest of MoveIt, no matter what you put in the launch files.

---

**Edit 2**:
To use a package from source, you just need to place the package directory (with its source files, include files, manifest.xml, etc.) somewhere in your `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.  Typically, you set up a workspace directory under your home directory to use for ROS development.  If this sounds confusing, you may need to revisit some of the early [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment).

You can use `rospack find sbpl_interface_ros` to see if ROS can find your package okay.  Once that works, you can do `rosmake sbpl_interface_ros` to build the package.  If this fails, it may be because you're also missing one of the dependencies for this package.  Use `rospack depends sbpl_interface_ros` to get a list of all package dependencies.  You'll need to install all these, either using binary packages or from source.  You can try using `rosdep install sbpl_interface_ros`, but this may not work for some packages.

---

**Edit 3:**
You should read the [FAQ](http://www.ros.org/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_install_ROS_packages_from_.deb_files.3F) to see how to install missing dependencies.  In short:

1. Go to the [ROS Wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki) and search for the package (upper right).
2. On the package's [wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/planning_models), see what stack the package is a part of.  In the case of `planning_models`, this is the `arm_navigation` package.
3. Try to install the binary package:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-<distro>-<stack>
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-arm-navigation
```

4. If that doesn't work, you'll need to install the package from source, like you've done already.  The package webpage will have a link to download the source, if needed.

*P.S. - Not to sound needy, but if you like this answer, please give it an upvote (up arrow near the top left of the answer) and/or click the check mark to flag it as accepted.  That way others can know that the question has already been addressed.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosrookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/3050/rosrookie/) on 2013-04-24**:
Thanks Jeremy for our answer. I followed your advive, but first I had to create the file sbpl_planning_pipline.launch (just copied and renamed in ompl_planning_pipline.launch and changed every ompl to sbpl). But while starting RVIZ with the MoveIt plugin some errors occur (see my post above)

**Comment by [rosrookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/3050/rosrookie/) on 2013-04-24**:
You're right. I used rospack and no sbpl-plugin was listed. Now how can I get the source-code (I'm a quiete newbie to that) I downloaded the source moveit folder, is that right?